# How to decleare and initialise a BigDecimal in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to call a java method from C++ code , for that i am using JNI, i am able to call java method but during call i want to use BigDecimal inside c++ , can you please help me to use BigDecimal( how to declared and initialize) in C++ code.

Comment: to the downvoter - this is a decent question.  "How do you declare a Java BigDecimal in a JNI C++ wrapper?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `BigDecimal` is just a java object for the native part.
So first you need to create it. Therefore you need a class and a method ID.

```
jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/math/BigDecimal");
jmethodID = mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "<init>", "(D)V");
```

This would be the Construtor of `BigDecimal` taking a double.
After this you can create two objects.

```
jobject bd1 = (*env)->NewObject(env,cls, mid, 1.222);
jobject bd2 = (*env)->NewObject(env,cls, mid, 0.0500);
```

Now you have two `BigDecimal` and you can add one to the other.
First you need the `add` methodID again.

```
jmethodID mid2 = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "add", "(Ljava/math/BigDecimal;)Ljava/math/BigDecimal;");
```

Then you can call it.

```
jobject sum = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env,bd1,mid2,bd2);
```

Now you have the sum of your first two `BigDecimal`. To print it out you could use the `doubleValue()` function.

Comment: actually i want to call java addition method having two BegDecimal value and return BigDecimal . e.g.  BigDecimal a = 1.222 ; BigDecimal b = 0.0500; BigDecimal result = a + b;  i have created a jclass and jmethodID in c++ but i am not sure how i declare two BigDecimal input value in C++ and after calling java method how to print BigDecimal result in C++ code again. pls help me

Comment: @user3504032: I changed the post. This should do what you want, although I did not compile the code so there might be typos. The output is a good exercise to understand how jni works. Give a try yourself.

Comment: if i want to convert mid2 to string value , how i will do this ?

Comment: @user3504032: What is the point of that? jmethodID is an opaque type. Is has no useful information for you. In some implementations it is just a typedef of int. But this is not for all VMs.

Comment: i have 1 java class com.fedex.test.BigDecimalDemo class which is having sum method :

Comment: mkaes: 
jobject bd1 = (*env)->NewObject(env,cls, mid, 1.222);
here we pass double value 1.222 , how to implement if i want to use string in place of double . e.g. string Arg1 = "1.222"; how i put Arg1 while creating object. also pls send me code to print bd1 .